# My iOS app Screen is not auto sizing in iOS 5 dimension

Tags: objective-c, iphone, screen

The Screen UI is developed for 3:2, but when I run the app in iOS Simulator for iphone 5 and above, I see there is a white patch below in the bottom of the screen. The rest of the screens are appearing correctly.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    [self startup];
    [window addSubview:loginViewController.view];

    //For Eula
    NSDictionary *eulaDict = [EULAController getEULADictionary];
    if (eulaDict == nil || [ self checkForVersionChange] == TRUE) {
        eulaController = [[EULAController alloc] initWithNibName:@"eula"bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        //temp fix as for some reason this is showing up 20 pixels shifted upwards. if this works in your scenario then remove this adjustment
        CGRect frame1 =  CGRectMake(0,20,320,460);
        [eulaController.view setFrame:frame1];
        [window addSubview:eulaController.view];
    }

    [self updateVersionAndBuild];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Not sure, why its not fitting the entire screen. I didn enable athe AutoLayout option but it didnt help, as during the launch of the app, it stops for iphone 5/6.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the Default-568h@2x.png default launch image...

If so, just add one to your project and it will work.

Comment: I have added the launch images correctly, for default-568h@2x.png, and with that all the screens are getting resized correctly. However, it is the login image, which is not resizing, I have added the screenshot of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You've hardcoded the frame to iPhone 4 size:

```
CGRect frame1 =  CGRectMake(0,20,320,460);
```

You've said your using autoLayout. I'd remove this and use autoLayout constraints instead and it will scale.

Comment: If did remove it, but the result is the same. If I tend to use AutoLayout, then I get this error.
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.
This is my XIB, which is defining this image, What can I do to make it understand that, it should use a smaller image for 4s and a different bigger image for 5s?
<imageView autoresizesSubviews="NO" opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" fixedFrame="YES" image="loginFinal.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="22">